# Do JavaScript event handlers get overwritten?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious if binding an event to an object multiple times cause problems by stacking multiple event listeners on top of each other or do they override each other?  For example if I have an attachHandlers function

```
function _attachHandlers() {

            // Slider hover
            var isDown = false;
            $('.ui-slider-handle').mousedown(function () {
                // Create tool tip
                isDown = true;

                var tt = $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('sk-tooltip');
                var handle = $(this);

                var left = parseInt(handle.css('left'));

                var val = _convertSliderValue(Math.round(left / 5 / 14.2857));
                tt.text(val);

                handle.append(tt);

                var newLeft = (handle.outerWidth() - tt.outerWidth()) / 2;
                tt.css({
                    'left': newLeft
                });


                $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
                    var left = parseInt(handle.css('left'));

                    var val = _convertSliderValue(Math.round(left / 5 / 14.2857));
                    tt.text(val);

                    var newLeft = (handle.outerWidth() - tt.outerWidth()) / 2;
                    tt.css({
                        'left': newLeft
                    });
                });

            });

            $(document).mouseup(function () {
                if (isDown) {
                    $(document).unbind('mousemove');

                    $(this).find('.sk-tooltip').remove()
                    isDown = false;
                }

            });
        }
```

I need to re-attach these handlers at some point in my code and therefore I was just going to call `_attachHandlers()` to re-bind them, however, I will also be re-binding the `document` listener for the mouseup event every time this happens. Therefore, is it alright to do this and will the event handler just get overwritten everytime or do I have to unbind the handler first before it can be re-bound?

Comment: No, nothing gets overwritten, the handler will be bound multiple times. And then be fired multiple times when an even occurs! You need to explicitly unbind it.

Comment: note that @Bergi's answer applies because you're using jQuery. And that the elaborate answer is found in the jQuery API documentation, which says that the functions you're using are shorthand for `.on()`, which explains in detail how event handling in jQuery works, over on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Mike: My comment actually applies to non-jQuery event handling as well - unless you use the [old, traditional model](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) of binding events.

Comment: in a world of w3schools, not an unrealistic scenario. (or in a world where a mutually exclusive handler is necessary)